# C# passing a string to an Sqlite parameter

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to pass a string (the output of a function) to an SqLite query and have it update a database with it. I get an error telling me that string is not a valid data type.

```
  IList<string> classList = new List<string>(){ "Saber", "Archer", "Lancer", "Rider",
     "Caster", "Assassin", "Berserker", "Ruler", "Avenger", "Moon Cancer"};
    public string setClass(int uid)
    {
        string newClass;
        int remainder = uid % 10;
        newClass = classList[remainder];
        return(newClass);
    }
    [NadekoCommand, Usage, Description, Aliases]
    public async Task initialiseClasses()
    {
        using (SqliteConnection _db = new SqliteConnection(@"Filename=.\myDb.db"))
        {
            _db.Open();
            string newSQL = "ALTER TABLE DiscordUser ADD Class char";
            SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(newSQL, _db);
            command.ExecuteReader();
            string tempClass = setClass(7);  //temporary input
            newSQL = "UPDATE DiscordUser SET Class = @newClass";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@newClass", SqliteType.Text).Value = tempClass);
            command = new SqliteCommand(newSQL, _db);
            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass tempClass into the Sqlite query.

Comment: Common mistake. You are adding the `Value` of the parameter to the parameters collection instead of the actual parameter. Don't try to do everything in one line of code, it is difficult to reason about.

Comment: We don't put solved in the title here.  Just checking the accepted answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You were creating a new command **after** you assigned the parameter to the command which resulted in a command without parameters being executed.
2. The `Add` on the parameter collection can be rewritten so it is more fluent, see change below.
3. `ExecuteReader` should be `ExecuteNonQuery`

If you structure your code with `using` blocks it is easier to see the scope of the command instance. See below:

```
public async Task initialiseClasses()
{
    using (SqliteConnection _db = new SqliteConnection(@"Filename=.\myDb.db"))
    {
        _db.Open();
        string newSQL = "ALTER TABLE DiscordUser ADD Class char";
        using(SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(newSQL, _db))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string tempClass = setClass(7);  //temporary input
        newSQL = "UPDATE DiscordUser SET Class = @newClass";
        using(SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(newSQL, _db))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@newClass", SqliteType.Text).Value = tempClass;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, this worked wonderfully - thank you! Such a silly mistake